# save table data angular 2 created from ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating an editable table from the data that I am getting from the back end now I want to save the data that has been updated. 
I have tried using formControl but it only save the data that is in the last column
Here is my code

```
    <form [formGroup]="pagesForm">
        <tr *ngFor="let data of pagesArray; let i = index;  trackBy: trackByFn">
           <td style="text-align: center;" >
              <input type="text" formControlName="nameControl" value=[data.name]>
          </td>
           <td style="text-align: center;">
               <input type="text" formControlName="descriptionControl" 
               vaue=[data.description]>
           </td>

         </tr>
    <button class="btn btn-common" (click)="submit(pagesForm)">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Can anyone help me to save this table data in bulk

Comment: vaue=data.name] missing "[ "

Comment: vaue = value / spelling error ?

Comment: Thanks for the correction Can you help me in this

Comment: well i never used formControlName. I only use `<input [(ngModel)]="data.name" name="name">`

Comment: I also used ngModel but there also it picks up the last value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of reactive form, which I suggest, especially when dealing with an array... with that you need a `FormArray` to which you push your values when you get them from the backend.

So you can build your form:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.pagesForm = this.fb.group({
    arr: this.fb.array([])
  })
}
```

and when you receive your data, in the callback (`subscribe` or `then` if you are using promises) call a method, in this example `setFormArray()` that populates your form array:

```
setFormArray() {
  let arr = this.pagesForm.controls.arr;
  this.pagesArray.forEach(x => {
    arr.push(this.fb.group({
      name: x.name,
      description: x.description
    }))
  })
}
```

Then you can modify your template to iterate the formarray:

```
<form [formGroup]="pagesForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(pagesForm.value)">
  <div formArrayName="arr">
    <tr *ngFor="let page of pagesForm.controls.arr.controls; let i = index" 
        [formGroupName]="i" >
      <td>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" formControlName="description">
      </td>    
    </tr>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Now you end up with an form object that contains property `arr`, which is an array of your data.

Here's a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/zfpbUzkvMLOn8CCermGD?p=preview

Hope this helps! :)